# Returning std::string properly using Move Semantics

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

Consider a function that returns a large string:

```
std::string build_huge_string(unsigned long size)
{
    std::string result;
    result.reserve(size);

    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        result.push_back(i % 256);

    return result;
}
```

It's used somewhere maybe like this `std::string huge_string = build_huge_string(65536);`
Is there a way to make sure the contents of `result` are moved into `huge_string` without 64KB worth of stuff being copied?

Is that how it happens by default? Should `build_huge_string` return `std::string&&`? Should `return result;` be replaced with `return std::move(result);`?

Comment: tl;dr: `return result;` _already_ either implicitly moves the value or directly constructs it in the caller's location. `return std::move(result);` prevents direct construction. Returning a `std::string&&` would be a dangling reference - don't do if you're returning a local variable.